# How can i clear the text in a text field with a button in swift 3?

Tags: ios, macos, textfield

I want to make a text editor and want a reset button, but I don't know I can reset the `UITextField`.

Here´s my code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func Quit(_ sender: Any) {

    exit(0)

}

@IBAction func Reset(_ sender: Any) {



}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}


}
```

Comment: set textField.text = "" inside the reset action

Comment: textField.text = @""

Comment: @"" ? how very objective-C

Comment: @jacob may be you are new, before asking question search , if you dont get then post question.

Comment: Yes but it did not work so i asked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the text empty the text property:

```
self.textField.text = ""
```

or

```
self.textField.text = nil
```

That line of code must be in your button action

I also recomend to dont use NS objects. You can import UIKit and use TexField instead of NSTextField, and ViewController instead of NSViewController

Comment: I get an error when i try to import UIKit that says No such module UIKit. What can i do

Comment: UIKit is only for iOS not OSX sorry for not saying its for a mac programm.

Comment: ohh thats it. Anyway, the textfield line should works.

Comment: It does not work it just says "Value of NSTextfield has no member text" do you know what that is?

Comment: try with self.textField.stringValue = ""

Comment: Done, THX again